# angular: pass data when doing a $location.path()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two views right now.

- login
- main

Right now I login and change my path to `/main` which works fine. When I am not logged in, and try to visit `/main` my web service returns `"Access denied for user anonymous"` which I then forward them to `/` which is my login view. How can I pass something so my `LoginController` knows they were forwarded from `/main` to alert them to login first?

`LoginController.js`

```
VforumJS.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, LoginModel)
{
    $scope.email        = "";
    $scope.password     = "";
    $scope.fetching     = false;
    $scope.error        = null;

    $scope.login = function()
    {
        $scope.error    = null;
        $scope.fetching = true;
        LoginModel.login($scope.email, $scope.password);
    }

    $scope.$on('LoginComplete', function(event, args)
    {
        log('login complete: ' + args.result);
        $scope.fetching = false;
        if (args.result == "success")
        {
            $location.path('/main');
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.error = args.result;
        }
    });
});
```

`MainController.js`

```
VforumJS.controller('MainController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, MainModel)
{
    $scope.currentTitle     = '-1';
    $scope.presentationData = MainModel.getPresentations();

    $scope.$on('PresentationsLoaded', function(event, args)
    {
        log(args.result);
        if (args.result != "Access denied for user anonymous")
        {
            //-- Parse preso data
            $scope.presentationData = args.result;
        }
        else
        {
            //-- Need to login first, route them back to login screen
            $location.path("/");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$location.search()` in your `MainController` to pass query string to the `LoginController`.

Inside you `MainController`:

```
    if (args.result != "Access denied for user anonymous")
    {
        //-- Parse preso data
        $scope.presentationData = args.result;
    }
    else
    {
        //-- Need to login first, route them back to login screen
        $location.search({ redirectFrom: $location.path() });
        $location.path("/");
    }
```

And then in your `LoginController`, shortened for brevity:

```
VforumJS.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, LoginModel)
{
    var queryString = $location.search();

    $scope.$on('LoginComplete', function(event, args)
    {
        log('login complete: ' + args.result);
        $scope.fetching = false;
        if (args.result == "success")
        {
            if (queryString && queryString.redirectFrom) {
                $location.path(queryString.redirectFrom);
            } else {
                $location.path('/somedefaultlocation');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.error = args.result;
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can use a shared service, maybe even your LoginModel to set a parameter from MainController to indicate the redirect came from it.

**Update**
Even better still, use `$httpProvider.interceptors` to register a response interceptor, and then use the same `$location.search()` technique described above to redirect to the login screen on authentication failure. This method is ideal as your controllers are then clean of authentication logic.

Comment: excellent, using $location.search() worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location) broadcasts `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess` events, and the third param of each is `oldUrl`.

One solution would be to have a service that subscribes to `$locationChangeStart` in order to save the current and old urls.

When you hit `/`, your `LoginController` can check your service to see if the oldUrl is `/main`, and then act accordingly.